# Unit testing a Django query set

Tags: python, django, django-unittest, python-unittest

I'm trying to learn unit testing with Django/unittest.

These are simple versions of my models:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_ips(self):
        return DeviceIP.objects.filter(device=self.id)


class DeviceIP(models.Model):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
```

And this is the test code I've come up with:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class DeviceTest(TestCase):

    def test_get_ips(self):
        device = Device()
        device.name = 'My Device'

        ip1 = DeviceIP()
        ip1.ip = '127.0.0.1'
        ip1.device = device
        ip1.save()

        ip2 = DeviceIP()
        ip2.ip = '127.0.0.2'
        ip2.device = device
        ip2.save()

        ip3 = DeviceIP()
        ip3.ip = '127.0.0.3'
        ip3.device = device
        ip3.save()

        self.assertEqual(device.get_ips(), [ip1, ip2, ip3])
```

The test results fails because on an `AssertionError` even though the string representations of `device.get_ips()` and `[ip1, ip2, ip3]` are identical.

If I try using `self.assertListEqual` I get an error because `device.get_ips()` is a QuerySet and not a list.

If I try `self.assertQuerySetEqual` I get an error saying "`DeviceTest object has no attribute assertQuerySetEqual`" but I'm not sure why because `DeviceTest` extends `django.test`'s TestCase.

How should I be doing a test like this?

Also, in a "real" project would it make sense to do such a simple test?

Comment: Are you aware that using `device.deviceip_set.all()` is Django's built in way to do what your `get_ips()` method does? Look at Django's documentation for reverse foreign keys. You also don't need to test it then, as it's standard Django behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I've only just started learning Django and wasn't aware of that. I'll switch to using that approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call `device.get_ips()` returns a `QuerySet` whereas `[ip1, ip2, ip3]` is a list. Hence they're currently not equal.

Given that you don't want to test things that may not matter (order in which rows are returned in `.filter()` from the database), I suggest testing as follows:

```
results = device.get_ips()
result_ips = [ip.ip for ip in results]
self.assertEqual(len(results), 3)
self.assertTrue(ip1.ip in result_ips)
self.assertTrue(ip2.ip in result_ips)
self.assertTrue(ip3.ip in result_ips)
```

This tests: three results and IPs are the same. This should give reasonable confidence that you're getting the same objects (although you can add more assertions as desired).

Comment: Or since the inputs are unique, just apply sorting in the assert which will take care of both list length and contents.  `self.assertEqual(sorted(result_ips), sorted([ip1,ip, ip2.ip, ip3.ip]))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comment which both worked for me. I'm going to change to using `deviceip_set()` as Ben recommended above, but this is exactly what I needed to understand how to approach this type of testing. @AustinPhillips, minor typo: `ip1,ip` should be `ip1.ip`

Answer (score 10):

Actually the right way, and recommended by djangoproject is:

```
    self.assertEqual(list(device.get_ips()), [ip1, ip2, ip3])
```

Forcing `sorted` on queryset and list will change your testing scenario and you don't want it.

Answer (score 1):

You typed `self.assertQuerySetEqual` and it should be `self.assertQuerysetEqual`, try:

```
self.assertQuerysetEqual(device.get_ips(), [repr(ip1), repr(ip2), repr(ip3)], 
                         ordered=False)
```

Or if you still want to test it against a list:

```
self.assertItemsEqual(device.get_ips(), [ip1, ip2, ip3])
```